# How can I enqueue comment-reply script only on certain page?

Tags: php, comments, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to enqueue comment-reply.js script only on a certain page but something is wrong with my code. Can someone hint things here?

```
<?php if ( is_singular('1740') && (!is_home() || !is_front_page() || !is_single()) && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments') ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
```

Comment: I think `is_singular()` accepts only str|array of post type name, not a post ID.  You could use [`is_single`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) or [`is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/). Unless `1740` is a valid CPT :D

Comment: @SamuelElh I think that the problem was `is_singular('1740')`. I ended up using this and it worked: `<?php if ( is_page('1740')) {wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the conditional tag which is `comments_open()` is not required. That checks if the comments are allowed for that specific page or not.

Try using the following code

```
<?php
if ( is_single('1740') ||
( !is_home() || !is_front_page() || !is_single() ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
} ?>
```

`comments_open()` requires the post ID for the specific posts to check whether the comments are allowed or not. So avoid using the condition for that.

Don't use `is_singular()` with ID as it checks if a singular post is being displayed using the post type name as a parameter. Instead use `is_single()` with using the post ID for which you wish to display.

In your above code, the flower bracket was missing too for the if condition.

Hope that helps the question you have asked.

Comment: not working... Even with your code I get comment-reply on home/front_page and single posts... What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code and let me know

```
if ( is_singular('1740') && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
```